# Incomplete downloads over curl-sftp and curl-scp with curl 7.46.0 package

Tags: linux, curl, libcurl

I am trying to do curl sftp download.

My version of curl is 7.46.0 and libssh2 is 1.6.0

I am getting this error

/tmp # curl -kv  scp://10.12.16.16//var/lib/tftpboot/lokesh/sw_data.img -u root:root123 -o /tmp/sw_data.img

- Trying 10.12.16.16...

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
  Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
- Connected to 10.12.16.16 (10.12.16.16) port 22 (#0)
- SSH MD5 fingerprint: 72b2890c38059d8d3509dfacbd69c5cb
- SSH authentication methods available: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
- Using SSH public key file '(nil)'
- Using SSH private key file ''
- SSH public key authentication failed: Unable to extract public key from private key file: Unable to open private key file
- Initialized password authentication
- Authentication complete
- SSH CONNECT phase done
  { [16384 bytes data]

  42 7680k   42 3232k    0     0   5900      0  0:22:12  0:09:20  0:12:52   0

Only partial amount of file is downloaded as speed stops to zero.

How to resolve this problem?
Do I need to add some compilation options while cross-compiling this?
I tried with "curl sftp" too, the same problem partial download is observed?
But with the old version of curl-7.37.1, this issue is not seen.
Please help me in this regard.

Comment: sounds like a possible bug in curl or libssh2, this is not the place to deal with such...

Comment: then where can we discuss this kind of problems? what is that "possible bug" ?

Comment: The libcurl mailing list probably a good start!